# CSS Style value possible characters?

Tags: css

Any of the following characters appear in CSS style's value?

- ^
- <
- >
- ;
- =
- {
- }

I am working an an application which allows users to customize some section in the page. They can select the style (background-color, font-size, etc) from a drop down, and they can provide custom value for the selected styles. I am creating a filter to stop invalid values. the url keyword is not allowed in the value so no background-image etc.

Comment: http://w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: @DanielRHicks if I could I'd -1 you for w3schools.

Comment: (I'm guessing this is a homework question.)

Comment: @Truth -- You must never ask difficult questions.

Comment: @Truth actually I am working on an application which allows users to customize pages so working on a filter to generate error on "possible" invalid css styles values. User can select the style (like background-color or font-size) from a drop-down list, but can enter the value he wants.

Comment: Oh well, in that case, all of them may appear. the `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements allow the `content: "value";` property which allows any character inside of it.

Comment: @Truth user is not allowed to enter the style manually, he can only enter the value for style so :before/:after are not possible.

Comment: In which case all I can think of is the url(''); of `background`. It should also allow most if not all of these.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a value of a CSS property: Yes, they can. E.g:

```
div {
    background: url("this can be any wicked thig.");
}
```

Comment: Well that's kind of cheating since you're referring to a string ;) But you have a valid point nevertheless...

Comment: @BoltClock: A well written robust parser must be prepared to such crazinesses like strings :D

Comment: Just checked windows don't allow < and > in file names, but allows the rest.

Comment: Then that's an OS limitation and has nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `=` is used:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
```

I don't know how you would interpret that but maybe all characters are used:

```
@-webkit-keyframes myanim { 
  0%   { opacity: 0.0; }
  50%  { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
```

Comment: Your first example is not valid CSS.

Comment: @Rob First example is for internet explorer rotate element 45 deg